# Connecting GitHub in IntelliJ

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, failed-to-connect

I am trying to connect GitHub in my IntelliJ. I attempted it in two ways, first with my username and password, I got this message,
"You are being redirected to the authorized application. If your browser does not redirect you back, please click here to continue."
I also tried with a token, but I got this message,
"Invalid authentication data, connection timed out".

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: When u r directed to a authorization web page, you need to click the button to authorize it

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid authentication data, connection timed out" - there is a chance that you may have proxy configured either in your system or under Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy.
So it worth checking it, and if it's in place - please try to disable it.